# How to use the ref property in a react-native-paper TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I'm trying to use the react-native-paper TextInput as a field to show a location search input. This doesn't seem to work because the ref property on this component doesn't get registered. How can I add a ref property to this field?

Comment: Please add your non-working code and what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';

 const [text, setText] = React.useState("");
 const textRef=React.useRef(); //add this

 <TextInput
      ref={textRef} //add this
      label="Email"
      value={text}
      onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
    />
```

Comment: I tried this, the problem is that this component is suitable for google maps location search because it isn't a htmlinputelement.